Determining statistical significance
I am trying to determine the statistical significance of my results at a 95 percent confidence level. I have the coefficients and the standard errors. I wanted to check if the following statement is correct - if I do a coefficient +/- 1.96 and if 0 falls within that range then it's not statistically significant at a level of 0.05. Is that correct? Or is it standard error +/- 1.96

To construct a $95\%$ confidence interval around the coefficient, $1.96$ is the amount you scale the standard error by, not the amount you add/subtract. This $1.96$ is also only appropriate if the sampling distribution of the coefficient is (approximately) normal, because $$\begin{aligned}z_{0.025} &\approx -1.96 \\ z_{0.975} &\approx +1.96 \end{aligned}$$ for the inverse cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution ($z$), specifically.
If the sampling distribution of the estimate is indeed normal and zero lies within $$\textrm{Estimate} \,\pm\, 1.96 \times\textrm{SE},$$ then the estimate does not differ significantly from zero.

Use of the term "coefficient" in this answer seems odd; estimate, or statistic? Also, one should really use $t_0.025$ etc., instead of z, but that is probably unneeded complexity for the OP's question.

@jginestet Coefficient was used in the question and normal approximations for coefficients are not uncommon at all (e.g. GLM).

@FransRodenburg: Thank you for this. Does that also mean that if the interval does not include zero, then the coefficient is statistically significant?

@KarishmaD'Souza If the null-hypothesis is that it is zero, then yes.
